# Get the Base Url in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem to get the url written in browser's address bar, I have tried this solution:

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

but it return the full path. I just want to get the url part, without sub-domain part, as displayed in the picture, I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing works

[descriptive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vVrb.png)

Comment: remove `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI';`

Comment: Thanks but it is related to many other websites so the url is false I want just to get the one written in navigator url (where we write the url) , that is it

Comment: Try with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: Thanks all but that is not what I meant at least is there any solution to get domain param in cookies

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
 <?php 

     function getbaseurl($url) {

     $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
     return $domain;
   }

     echo getbaseurl('https://www.carlo.in/new-cars/bmw');

  ?>
```

**You will get**  :  carlo.in

Comment: it's simple and easy to get.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right you want to remove "www" sub-domain prefix.

You can use `parse_url()` function for that:

```
$info = parse_url($url);
$host = $info['host'];
```

Or in your case:

```
$info = parse_url($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$host = $info['host'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the URL : `http://www.wallpapersuper.com`

PHP

```
<?php echo str_replace('www.','', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);?> // wallpapersuper.com
```

Javascript

```
var str = window.location.href;
document.write(str.replace("http://www.", ""));
```

Comment: please format your code with code tags to improve readability

Comment: This question is for PHP, not JS.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer but I need solution with php

Comment: Copied from http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-action-self.html and probable spam